# How do cordless lawn mowers determine lawn density?

Tags: sensors

Some cordless lawn mowers have a feature that causes the motor to cut off when the mower is rolled over a driveway or over a section of lawn where the grass is very sparse.  How does the mower sense this condition?

Comment: I don't know how mowers do it, but an obvious way would be to monitor the motor current and RPM, and switch off the motor when the torque drops or the speed rises because nothing is being cut.

Comment: My experience has been the opposite: more power is automatically used when the grass is more dense, or taller.